# Bypass AppEngine Edge Cache

Tags: google-app-engine, cloudflare

I'm using an AppEngine Standard project with some custom CloudFlare page rules to cache some API endpoints with a custom Edge Cache TTL.

When the data on those endpoints change, I use CloudFlare API to clear CloudFlare Edge cache for that URLs, but the same cannot be achieved with AppEngine Edge Cache, that is automatically enabled when a header like this is found in the response and there is no way to clear it:

`Cache-Control: public, maxage=TTL`

`Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=TTL`

Is there any way to disable or bypass AppEngine cache for certain URLs even it they responded with a `Cache-Control` header?

Another solution would be use special cache headers for CloudFlare but, as far as I know, it only recognizes the standard `maxage` and `s-maxage` Cache-control directives (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-)

I made this diagram to help clarify my question:
[image]

Comment: it happen same to me

Comment: I'm using `s-maxage` and it's working fine, looks like appengine don't recognize it